# Parsing specific column's using inputs

Tags: python, parsing, text, text-files

I've been trying to wrap my head around a method of parsing a text file and specifying the specific columns you want. So for example I ask them to input what columns they want to parse out of the text file.

```
Names.txt
Joe,Smith,19,15,17
Jake,Jones,19,15,17
Bob,Martin,19,15,17
```

So the person will input the txt file and then inputs that they want Column 0 and 2 it will give them a result of

```
Joe,19
Jake,19
Bob,19
```

I know I can do the .split()[0] but I dont want to hard code it I want it to work off the input. Im pretty sure its easy but for some reason I just cant get my head around the way to do it.

---

To make it a bit more in depth I want to make a program that you input a txt file and it asks you for what sections you would like then it prints out the seconds you wanted.

```py
InputFileName = input("Please enter the name of file you would like to parse: ")
ParseSelection = input("Please enter the section's you want to parse: ")
```

and then from that it will open the txt file see that the user asked for Section 0 and 2 and just print them out as "Section 0 | Section 2"

```
Names.txt
Joe,Smith,19,15,17
Jake,Jones,19,15,17
Bob,Martin,19,15,17
```

open Names.txt it see that the person asked for Section 0 and 2 So it prints out

```
Joe | 19
Jake | 19
Bob | 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but i'll attempt to help you here.
You're on the right lines, however for comma separated text it would be best to do this:

```
input().split(',')[0:4:2]
```

You can always use modules like this also (much easier):-
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
columns = list('02')
```

where the input, '02', would indicate the user wants columns 0 and 2.
Then you iterate over the file's lines and columns:

```
for lines in file:
    for column in columns:
        print(lines[int(column)], end=',')
    print()
```

With your example, that'd return

```
Joe,19,
Jake,19,
Bob,19,
```

Also, if you're wondering how to read the input file, you may want to use the csv library.